# BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress returns BZ_OUTBUFF_FULL

Tags: c, linux, bzip2

I'm using [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2-manual-1.0.5.html#bzbufftobuffdecompress) to decompress my buffer data

```
unsigned char decrypted_data[500000] = {'\0'};
size_t decrypted_len = 0;
int decrypted_ret = BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress(decrypted_data,
                           &decrypted_len,
                           p_rsrc_data[0].data,
                           p_rsrc_data[0].size,
                           0,
                           4);
```

and p_rsrc_data[0].data length is 691, this:

[image]

and BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress return -8, this is BZ_OUTBUFF_FULL

Comment: `decrypted_len` is an in-out parameter. It should be set to 500000. According to [Utility functions | BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/util-fns.html): *"If the destination buffer is big enough, *destLen (decrypted_len) is set to the size of the uncompressed data, and BZ_OK is returned"*.

Comment: @jww Thanks first,it works for me, I set `decrypted_len` to 50000, then BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress decompress successfully.